# CSS & HTML menu div's

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS code

```
body
            {                          
                font-family: 'Verdana', 'Verdana', sans-serif;
                font-size: 15px;                
            }
            div.clear { clear: both; }
            #menubar { margin: 40px; position: ;}
            div.menu, div.menu ul { width: 100%; }
            div.menu ul
            {
                margin: 2px;
                padding: 0;
                list-style: decimal;
            }
            div.menu ul, div.menu li { float: left; }
            div.menu li { display: inline; }
            div.menu li a
            {               
                border-radius: 5px;
                background: #BDBDBD;
                text-decoration: none;
                border: solid 2px gray;                
                display: block;
                color: black;
            }
            div.menu a.first
            {
                background-position: right 0;
            }
            div.menu a.last
            { background-position: right 0; }
            div.menu a span
            {                
                height: 30px;
                line-height: 30px;
                color: black;
                display: block;
                padding: 3px;                          
            }                   

            div.menu li:hover a { background-position: -10px -30px; background: #d8dbd9;}
            div.menu li a:active { background-position: -10px -82px; }
            div.menu li:hover a.first { background-position: right -30px; }
            div.menu li a.first:active { background-position: right -52px; }
            div.menu li:hover a.last { background-position: right -30px; }
            div.menu li a.last:active { background-position: right -52px; }            

            div.menu div.menu
            {
                position: absolute;               
                display:  inline-block;
                margin-left:  170px;
                margin-top: -40px;
            }          
            div.menu div.menu div.menu
            {            
                margin-top: -40px;
                margin-left: 400px;
                display: block;
            }          
            div.menu div.menu ul, div.menu div.menu li, div.menu div.menu li a
            {
                float: none;
            }
            div.menu div.menu li a
            {
                display: block;
            }           
            div.menu div.menu li a
            div.menu div.menu div.menu li a
            {               
                background: none;
                border: #FF8040;
                margin: 2px;                                            
            }

            div.menu div.menu span,
            div.menu div.menu li:hover li span,
            div.menu div.menu li:hover li:hover li span
            {               
                border-radius: 5px;
                background: #BDBDBD;                    
                display: block;
                color: black;
                padding: 3px;                                 
            }

            div.menu div.menu li:hover span,
            div.menu div.menu li:hover li:hover span,
            div.menu div.menu li:hover li:hover li:hover span
            {
                background-color: #d8dbd9;
            }                       
            div.menu div.menu a span
            {
                display: block;            
            }           


            div.menu div.menu { display: none; }
            div.menu li:hover div.menu { display: inline-block; }

            div.menu li:hover div.menu div.menu { display: none; }
            div.menu div.menu li:hover div.menu { display: inline-block; }

            div.menu li:hover div.menu div.menu div.menu { display: none; }
            div.menu div.menu div.menu li:hover div.menu { display: block; }

            div.menu li:hover div.menu div.menu div.menu div.menu { display: none; }
            div.menu div.menu div.menu div.menu li:hover div.menu { display: block; }
```

And HTML index.html code:

```
<html>
        <head>
           <title>title</title>            
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="index_style.css" type="text/css"/>                                 
        </head>                                           


            <body> 
           <?php // setting header here ?>                                 
            <div id="menubar" class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li>
                <a target="_blank" href="somepage.php" class="no-children"><span>1</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>               
            </ul>
            <ul>  

            <ul>
                <li>
                <a target="_blank" href="#" class="has-children"><span>2</span></a>
                <div class="menu">
                        <ul>                                                      
                            <li>
                                <a target="_blank" href="somepage.php" class="has-children"><span>3</span></a>                                
                            </li>

                                <li>
                                    <a href="#" class="has-children"><span>4</span></a>
                                    <div class="menu">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="somepage.php"><span>5</span></a> 
                                        </li>                                           
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="somepage.php" class="has-children"><span>6</span></a>                                            
                                        </li>                                                                                                                                              
                                    </ul>
                                    <div class="clear"></div>
                                </div>
                                </li>                         
                        </ul>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>          
                </li> 
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li>
                <a target="_blank" href="somepage.php" class="no-children"><span>7</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li>
                <a target="_blank" href="somepagephp" class="no-children"><span>8</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>                                           
            <div class="clear"></div>                                                                
        </div>
        </body>        
    </html>
```

But the 2nd and 3rd level menu items don't display correctly, they have a whole-page with, I need it the widh by a content. Trying to make it the entire day. Thanks.

Comment: looks to me, at the very least as though you have way too many `ul`s in there. They seem to be wrapping each top level `li`. It looks quite odd.

Comment: Am I reading correctly that you have five nested menus divs? Have you tried naming each nested div differently than the one above it? eg <div class="menulevel1"><div class="menulevel2"><div class=menulevel3> and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was at separation `div.menu` and `div.menu li a`. Just had to set the pistion of div at `div.menu` section and it's size at `div.menu li a` section. It just depends on the experience.